# Should "page-break-inside: always;" work if applied inside a DIV?

Tags: css

For XHTML formatted as PDF output, IF an XHTML element is contained within a DIV, AND that contained element's class includes *page-break-before: always;*, THEN should there be a page break before that element?

In an XHTML authoring product I have created a CSS class that specifies *page-break-before*:

```
.TopOfPage /* Force an element to the top of the next PDF page */
{
    margin-top: 0em;
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

It works just fine until I wrap the content in a DIV that gives me control over the position of the main content flow relative to an XHTML topic's BODY element:

```
div.bodyAlignment   /* In @media print, position topic's content flow relative to the topic's BODY element */
{
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 2em;
    padding: none;
}
```

After I wrap the content in that DIV the page breaks stop working — it's as if *page-break-before* is no longer specified. (Although I know it is because I temporarily added *color: orange;* to the *.TopOfPage* class so I could verify it was being applied. Orange text resulted as expected but NOT the desired page breaks.)

So am I seeing the correct behavior of *page-break-before* when it is asserted within a DIV? Or am I seeing a product-specific failure to properly process the *page-break-before* attribute when it's inside a DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the authoring product's support folks just informed me that "The behavior regarding the div overriding the page-break-before property is a bug." Good to know both with regard to the product and with regard to CSS in general.